# Speed up looping through pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

It's easy to find ways to find questions regarding speeding up and vectorizing loops through rows of pandas dataframes. But what about columns?

Let's say I captured some lagged features as columns, and my dataframe is of this form:

```
feature_1 | feature_1_lag_1 | feature_1_lag_2 | feature_1_lag_3 | feature_2 | feature_2_lag_1 | ... | feature_n_lag_3
```

now, if I wanted, let's say to calculate the ratio of each feature against the average, the maximum, and the minimum of their lags I could do

```
for feature in feature_list:
    feature_lags_names = ["{}_lag_{}".format(feature, range(1, 4)]
    df["{}_ratio_against_avg".format(feature)] = df[feature] / df[feature_lags_names].mean(axis=1) 
    df["{}_ratio_against_min".format(feature)] = df[feature] / df[feature_lags_names].min(axis=1) 
    df["{}_ratio_against_max".format(feature)] = df[feature] / df[feature_lags_names].max(axis=1)
```

The issue is, if I have hundreds of features, and if I want to calculate more and different aggregations, I would just end up adding operations to the for cycle and it would end up taking a very long time.

Any way to speed this up or vectorize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can `cut` these columns into separate files and call python code to do the aggregations on each - this way when you don't have to wait till the first column to finish before starting the second column. - This 'manual mutli-threading' method worked for me.